# Splines in Negative Binomial Regression

Tags: r, regression, multivariate-analysis, negative-binomial-distribution, splines

I am conducting a negative binomial regression, and some of my independent variables have distinct non-linear patterns. As I understand, a linear association between the dependent and independent variable isn't an assumption of negative binomial regression, but the association between log(dependent variable) and independent variables should be linear.

I used restricted cubic splines from the rms R package to determine splines that best describe the association between each independent variable and the dependent variable. I essentially determine the best fitting splines visually. Then I used these splines in a negative binomial regression.

My question is, is this a valid approach? I'm finding little information on negative binomial/poisson regression and splines in general. Is it reasonable to use several independent variables with restricted cubic splines in a multivariable model? Am I better off using GAM?

Comment: Maybe the work of Grace Waba will help you with this.

Comment: @Michael Presumably you mean [Grace *Wahba*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Wahba), but given the broad extent of her work you should probably narrow the scope of your comment down a bit (across all the decades she's been publishing, she'd have to have published over 150 papers, I'd think). Did you perhaps mean to refer to the book *Spline Models for Observational Data* or did you have some particular papers in mind?

Comment: A little clarification & more detail (as edits to the question) might help. Is "the association between each dependent variable and the independent variable" the right way round? What does "I essentially determine the best fitting splines visually" mean?

Comment: I corrected the independent/dependent thing. To fit a spline, I plot a loess curve over the scatterplot of independent vs dependent variable, and pick an RCS that is closest to the loess curve. As I understand, even if the splines for individual variables are accurate, if I include more than one variable with splines in the model, the prediction can become highly inaccurate.

Comment: There is no reason you cannot use splines with negative binomial regression.  Maybe you could ask a more specific question about your modeling? gam models is an alternative, if you want the flexibility of the spline to be decided by the data. Restricted cubic splines with prefixed flexibility makes for easier inference, though.